# Check condition in Perl regex for substitution

Tags: regex, perl, conditional-statements

I want to substitute a particular pattern in a file with some other string. But I want the substitution only when a particular string is not matched in pattern.

My code is as follows:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = 'C:\test_folder\file.txt';
my $pattern = undef;

my $read_handle = undef;
my $string = undef;

open($read_handle, "<", $filename)
        || die "$0: can't open $filename for reading: $!";

while ( <$read_handle> ){
     $string = $string.$_;
}


$pattern = qr/(TEST_CASE_NAME.*?:(.*?)\n.*?PRIORITY.*?:(\w\d).*?=cut)/s;

$string =~ s{$pattern}{$1\n\nsub $2\n{\n}\n}g;
print $string;
```

I have stored whole file in a string. 
I have following problem:

> If in pattern, $3(3rd back-reference) is not equal to "P3", then only substitution should occur. How can I achieve this?

Some sample data for input is:

> =head2 Gen_001
>
> TEST_CASE_NAME  :GEN_001
>   PRIORITY    :P0
>   RELEASE_INTRODUCED  :7.4
>     AUTOMATED   :YES
>
> STEP_NAME   : step1
>   STEP_DESC   :Example desc for understanding
>     STEP_RESULT :Example result for understanding
>
> =cut
>
> =head2 Gen_003
>
> TEST_CASE_NAME  :GEN_003
>   PRIORITY    :P1
>   RELEASE_INTRODUCED  :7.4
>     AUTOMATED   :NO
>
> STEP_NAME   : step1
>   STEP_DESC   :Example desc for understanding second
>   testcase
>   STEP_RESULT :Example result for understanding second
>   testcase
>
> =cut
>
> =head2 Gen_004
>
> TEST_CASE_NAME  :GEN_004
>   PRIORITY    :P3
>   RELEASE_INTRODUCED  :7.4
>     AUTOMATED   :NO
>
> STEP_NAME   : step1
>   STEP_DESC   :Example desc for understanding third
>   testcase
>   STEP_RESULT :Example result for understanding third testcase
>
> =cut

Comment: While this is already a good question, it would help to add example data. Without that, it's a bit hard to answer regex questions. You can [edit] the question to add some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a negative lookahead:

```
(TEST_CASE_NAME.*?:(.*?)\n.*?PRIORITY.*?:(?!P3)(\w\d).*?=cut)
                                         ^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJ5mD6/2)

The lookahead `(?!P3)` makes sure the next 2 characters matched by `(\w\d)` are not equal to `P3`.

Comment: *If in pattern, $3(3rd back-reference) is not equal to "P3", then only substitution should occur.* If we change `P3` in my demo to something else, there will be a match, and substitution will occur.